# Specifying HK2 names on injectee at bind time

Tags: java, hk2

I'm using HK2 for dependency injection across all of my REST microservices. When I create a Database Access Object (DAO), the constructor usually looks like

```
@Inject
public ServiceDao(final DataSource dataSource) {
    ...
}
```

and the app has an initialization block defining all of the bindings

```
@Override
protected void configure(ServiceConfig config, AbstractBinder binder) {
    binder.bind(config.dataSource).to(DataSource.class);
    binder.bind(ServiceDao.class).to(ServiceDao.class).in(Singleton.class);
}
```

I have a service that, for performance reasons, needs direct access to another service's database. I know that I *can* modify each DAO to have a `@Named` DataSource

```
public ServiceADao(final @Named("ServiceADataSource") DataSource) {
```

-

```
binder.bind(config.serviceADataSource)
      .named("ServiceADataSource")
      .to(DataSource.class);
```

However, is there any way that I can specify which DataSource each of my DAOs should use, without modifying the DAO code itself? (Using only the `AbstractBinder` that I have available in my configure block?)

Comment: One thing I can think is to use a `Factory` for the daos, and grab whatever data source you want from the `ServiceLocator`, and just construct the dao yourself with the appropriate data source.

Comment: Like peeskillet I can't think of any particular way to do this.  Other than a factory as suggested you could also probably implement an InjectionResolver (https://hk2.java.net/2.5.0-b05/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/InjectionResolver.html).  Also, in situations like this you might be able to use the Unqualified annotation so that you don't have to go around annotating *everything* (https://hk2.java.net/2.5.0-b05/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/Unqualified.html).  Hope that helps